# How to set a conditional depending on a range value in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to update my code in order to detect when a cell in column C is "Ready to process" or "Completed" and then insert a timestamp depending on which phrase is inserted.
Currently timestamps are inserted automatically in columns A & B but whichever change is done in column C.

[sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JwwQ.png)

my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimeStamp(e);
  }

function addTimeStamp(e) {

  // variables
  var startRow = 1;
  var ws = "2021";
  var targetColumn = 3;  

  // get modified row and columns  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col === targetColumn && row > startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2).setValue(new Date());
  }

  if (col === targetColumn && row > startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you want to set the same value if the value in column C is `"Ready to process"` or `"Completed"` or you want different values for each case.

But the following script contains separate if statements for each case, so you can add different values for `"Ready to process"` and `"Completed"` and it will only for them.

```
function addTimeStamp(e){
      const ar = e.range;
      const row = ar.getRow();
      const col = ar.getColumn();
      const as = ar.getSheet();
      if (as.getName()=="2021" && col == 3 && row > 1){
        if(ar.getValue()=="Ready to process" && as.getRange(row,1).getValue()==''){
           as.getRange(row,1).setValue("valueA"); 
        }
        else if (ar.getValue()=="Completed" && as.getRange(row,1).getValue()==''){
           as.getRange(row,1).setValue("valueB");
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that it worked!! 

Anyway, if I wanted to keep the first new Date() blocked and not updated any time some user change the status again, how could I manage it?